# browser.elements(...).forEach is not a function in webdriver.io

Tags: javascript, foreach

```
         search:{
               value: function(test) {
                   this.hope.click();
                   this.hope.setValue("abc");
                          var i=0;
                   browser.elements('//*[@class="xyz"]//li['+i+']').forEach((i, index)=>{
                       console.log(i.getText());
                       if(index==10) return;
                   })
               },
            },
```

Creating a function for consolidating elements but it results as forEach is not a function 
Result:TypeError: browser.elements(...).forEach is not a function.      Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong.

Comment: what does `browser.elements` return

Comment: that looks like an xpath argument, I know native xpath (available as document.evaluate in good browsers) do not ever return an array

Comment: does [this documentation](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/elements.html) relate to `browser.elements` - if so, you're clearly doing it wrong

Comment: Perhaps [*read the doco*](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/elements.html)?

Answer (score 0):

probably this

```
browser.elements('//*[@class="xyz"]//li['+i+']')
```

is not an array, you should check that before run a foreach